# Are attribute values like contents, glossary for `rel` attribute deprecated?

Tags: html, rel

I've been reading [this tutorial](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/More_about_the_document_head#Document_relationships_.E2.80.94_collating_several_HTML_documents_into_a_collection). When I cross cheked it with [MDN page on link_types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) I found that some values like *contents, glossary* and *copyright* aren't mentioned on MDN page. For *copyright* there seems to be an alternative of *license* value.

Am I reading an outdated tutorial? Are the values *contents, glossary* and *copyright* deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For current info on this, see the [existing rel values page in the Microformats Wiki](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values).

That page is what the HTML spec itself references as [the official list of `rel` values that are valid in addition the ones defined in HTML spec itself](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#other-link-types):

> Extensions to the predefined set of link types may be registered in the [microformats wiki existing-rel-values page](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values).

So you look there, you’ll see *contents*, *glossary* and *copyright* are all listed as valid `rel` values.

> For *copyright* there seems to be an alternative of *license* value.

Yes, they’re basically synonyms, where `rel=license` is the latest and `rel=copyright` is old<del>—though not formally deprecated. But given that [`rel=license` is among  the link types actually defined in the HTML spec itself](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#linkTypes), it’s *recommended* to instead use `rel=license` these days —but even that’s not formally mandated/required. (You can still safely use `rel=copyright` if you want.)</del>

#### 2016-03-06 update

So, the (now-deleted/struck-through) part I said above about `rel=copyright` not being formally deprecated is actually wrong. In fact the HTML standard says it “must not be used in documents”.

If you look at the [Link types section of the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#linkTypes) and scroll just past the table there, you’ll see the following sentence [[which I’m planning to have moved to make it harder to miss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645360/are-attribute-values-like-contents-glossary-for-rel-attribute-deprecated/35645679#35645679)]:

> Some of the types described below list synonyms for these values.
>   These are to be handled as specified by user agents, but must not be
>   used in documents.

And then if you look at end of [the section for rel=license](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#link-type-license), you’ll see that is says:

> **Synonyms:** For historical reasons, user agents must also treat the keyword "`copyright`" like the `license` keyword.

So that means the spec says that `rel=copyright` must not be used in documents.

So I’ll also soon be [changing the HTML Checker behavior to emit an error for `rel=copyright`](https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/254).

Comment: The link you've given says `rel="index"` is deprecated.

Comment: I think only the values mentioned in the official draft http://w3c.github.io/html/links.html#sec-link-types are recommended.

Comment: No, the values in http://w3c.github.io/html/links.html#sec-link-types are not the only `rel` values that are recommended. The spec makes it very clear that the values listed in that Microformats Wiki page are just as valid. And note that if you want to make sure you’re getting up-to-date information from the actual formal HTML Standard, you need to use https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/ (http://w3c.github.io/html/ is a manually-maintained forked copy that lags behind the standard).

Comment: Yes, `rel=index` is formally deprecated. Did anything in my answer imply that it wasn’t? Or do sources somewhere else say that it’s still valid? If so, any source that says `rel=index` is valid is wrong or out of date and needs to be corrected.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) thinks `index` is still allowed. I thought MDN is a good and an up-to-date source.

Comment: Even MDN is wrong sometimes :) That’s why they always welcome new contributors who want to help keep it up to date. (And note that a good way to get it touch with the MDN maintainer community is on the [#mdn channel on irc.mozilla.org](http://chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org%3A%2B6697&channel=%23mdn)

Comment: Also to be clear as far as resources in the https://www.w3.org/community space, note that those come with no endorsement at all from the W3C itself (they are autonomously community-maintained).  For better or worse, nobody is doing oversight of it, so it’s a bit of a free-for-all—some resources in that space are great, some not so much.